# Copy value of date field in YouTrack

Tags: javascript, youtrack

I want to copy the value from issues in one project to issues in another that depend on it.
That is what I have:

```
var entities = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/entities');
var workflow = require('@jetbrains/youtrack-scripting-api/workflow');

exports.rule = entities.Issue.onChange({
  // TODO: give the rule a human-readable title
  title: 'Date-propagation',
  guard: function(ctx) {
    var links = ctx.issue.links['depends on'];
    return ctx.issue.isChanged("Date") || !links.added.isEmpty() || !links.removed.isEmpty();
  },
  action: function(ctx) {
    var issue = ctx.issue;
    var links = issue.links['depends on'];
    function updateIssue(normalIssue){
      normalIssue.fields.DueDate = issue.fields.Date.value;
    }
    function checkList(list){
      if(list.isNotEmpty())list.forEach(function(normalIssue){updateIssue(normalIssue);}) ;
    }

    //checkList(links.removed);
    checkList(links);
    // TODO: specify what to do when a change is applied to an issue
  },
  requirements: {
    Date: {
      type: entities.Field.dateType,
    },
    Depend: {
      type: entities.IssueLinkPrototype,
      outward: 'is required for',
      inward: "depends on"
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is in this line:

```
normalIssue.fields.DueDate = issue.fields.Date;
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you do not have a 'DueDate' field on your instance (as the default field is called 'Due Date'). If so, your code line should look like this:

```
normalIssue.fields['Due Date'] = issue.fields.Date;
```